# Is $\sum_{n\geq 2}\left(\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2-1}} -1\right)$ convergent?

Tags: calculus, limits

How do I know if $\sum_{n\geq 2}\left(\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2-1}} -1\right)$ is convergent. Because I know that the limit of  $\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$ when x goes to infinite is 1, but that means nothing.

Comment: Are you asking all your homework questions one after the other? (cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2427264/sum-n-1-inftyn-sin-frac1n-1)

Comment: Αlso the O.P repeats the same sentence..''because i know....doesn't mean anything...''

Answer (score 2):

**hint**: $\dfrac{n}{\sqrt{n^2-1}} - 1= \dfrac{n-\sqrt{n^2-1}}{\sqrt{n^2-1}}= \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n^2-1}\left(n+\sqrt{n^2-1}\right)} <  \dfrac{K}{n^2}, K > 1 $ whereas $K$ is *constant* and can be determined.

Comment: Actually $K=1$ for every $n\geqslant2$, so one wonders what your idea was there. Anyway, the resulting solution is misleading. @upvoters Surely you understood the $K>1$ part since you upvoted this, care to explain?

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\displaystyle a_n=\frac  n{\sqrt{n^2-1}}-1=\left(1-\frac 1{n^2}\right)^{-1/2}-1\sim \frac {1}{2n^2}$ which is the general term of an absolutely summable series, so $\sum a_n$ converges as well.